# How to pass the array value to PHP using AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I am trying to submit data to the database using AJAX. I have one array and I have to pass the value of the array to PHP using AJAX to display all the related records.

```
<form id="search-form" method="POST">
  <input value="4869" name="compare_id[]" type="hidden">
  <input value="4884" name="compare_id[]" type="hidden">
  <input value="5010" name="compare_id[]" type="hidden">
  <input type="button" id="search-button" name="search-button" value="search">
</form>
<div id="response"></div>
```

**AJAX**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search-button').click(function(){
            $.ajax( {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'response.php',
                data: $('#search-form').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#response').html(response);
                    //alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
$sql='SELECT Name, Email FROM request WHERE Id IN (' .( is_array( $_POST['compare_id'] ) ? implode( ',', $_POST['compare_id']) : $_POST['compare_id'] ).')';

    $records = array();
    $query=$conn->query($sql);

    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row=$query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        $records[]=$row;
    }
}
echo json_encode($records);exit();
```

Comment: you are trying to add an array with string here `data:'all='+compare_id,`, convert your array in json then pass, or simply pass the array as `data:compare_id`,

Comment: fields in forms must have unique `id` and `name`

Comment: `compare_id.push($(this).val());` will get you the value of button not the hidden elements

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: @B.Desai, But I have same name and Id because with the help of AJAX I am displaying that input field.

Comment: @Hybreeder but it is invalid

Comment: @B.Desai, You are correct, I deleted ID. We can use name multiple times with array. Right?

Comment: Yes see solution of Matei Mihai below. It is perfect

Comment: @B.Desai but that code I tried, Nothing is happing when I clicked on button

Comment: update your question with edited code

Comment: @B.Desai, Updated my code.

Comment: check query proper and check records available or not

Comment: @B.Desai, Yes, Query is proper and fields are also available in this database

Comment: check my answer below change your script accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your script as below. Your output is in array so you cant add it in div directly

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search-button').click(function(){
            $.ajax( {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'action.php',
                data: $('#search-form').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                     $('#response').html();
                    for(data in response) //loop over your data
                    {
                      $('#response').append(response[data].Email);  //add email
                    }

                    //alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why the output is not displaying on the screen. I am getting output in the Network->XHR and I clicked on link and Response tab

Comment: Because it is in array. Try my code and tell `emails` are displaying  or not

Comment: Emails are displaying but not on screen. I check in network tab. How to display on screen

Comment: With above code also its not displaying on screen? Have you added this: `for(data in response) //loop over your data
                    {
                      $('#response').append(response[data].Email);  //add email
                    }` ?

Comment: Yes, It's working properly. There was an issue from my end. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<form id="search-form" method="POST">
  <input value="4869" name="compare_id[]" type="hidden">
  <input value="4884" name="compare_id[]" type="hidden">
  <input value="5010" name="compare_id[]" type="hidden">
  <input type="button" id="search-button" name="search-button" value="search">
</form>
<div id="response"></div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search-button').click(function(){
            $.ajax( {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'response.php',
                data: $('#search-form').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#response').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
var_dump($_POST['compare_id']);
// it is already an array of ids. You can do whatever you want with it.
```

Comment: just trying to posting same answer. but you have done faster +1  :)

Comment: @Matei Mihai, But When I clicked on the button then nothing is happing.

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your code. A good way to debug this is to `print_r`  your `POST` value in your php script.

First `$_POST["All"]` does not exist. It is `all`. (php)

Second, you send a `GET` request not a `POST` one. (jQuery)

Third, format your date into json. A good way to do this is to create a variable right after `compare_id.push`, it's more readable, as so :

```
var json_data = {"my_array" : [1,2, "bonjour", 4]};
```

Your problem is mostly related to "how to debug". I think you should print what's happening along the way to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for noticing bugs in the code @Pobe. Upvote from my side